# Pandas - Append dataframe to new excel sheet for multiple files

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want my new columns that are the output in a new sheet named "Analyzed Data" for multiple files. Each file has a different amount of columns with varying names.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\Me\1Test'
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        if not f.endswith('.txt'):
            continue
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, f))
for f in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(f)
    col = df.iloc[ : , : -3] 
    df['Average'] = col.mean(axis = 1)
    out = (df.join(df.drop(df.columns[[-3,-1]], axis=1)
               .sub(df[df.columns[-3]], axis=0)
               .add_suffix(' - Background')))
    out.to_excel(f.replace('txt', 'xlsx'), 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: Ok, and where specifically are you stuck implementing this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this for each file without explicitly calling onto each individual file. I know that I can call on a specific file as the excel writer and create a new sheet, but I assume that there is a more succinct way to do this across multiple files.